# Way to control the order of concatenation with browserify?

Tags: javascript, browserify

Say I have two files, a.ts and b.ts. a.ts has a class that extends from b.ts. If I attempt to browserify them using `browserify a.ts b.ts -p [ tsify --target='ES5' ] > test.js` then the outputted js for a.ts is always inserted before the js from b.ts.

My question is, is they a way to force browserify to add things to the output file in a specified order?

class A:

```
module Widget {
    export class A extends B {
        constructor() {
            super();
            console.log('monkey: ', this.getMonkey());
        }
    }
}
```

Class B:

```
module Widget {
    export class B {
        private monkey = 'Baboon';
        public getMonkey() {
            return this.monkey;
        }
    }
}
```

Combined outputted browserified JS:

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
var __extends = this.__extends || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    __.prototype = b.prototype;
    d.prototype = new __();
};
/// <reference path="B.ts" />
var Widget;
(function (Widget) {
    var A = (function (_super) {
        __extends(A, _super);
        function A() {
            _super.call(this);
            console.log('monkey: ', this.getMonkey());
        }
        return A;
    })(Widget.B);
    Widget.A = A;
})(Widget || (Widget = {}));

},{}],2:[function(require,module,exports){
var Widget;
(function (Widget) {
    var B = (function () {
        function B() {
            this.monkey = 'Baboon';
        }
        B.prototype.getMonkey = function () {
            return this.monkey;
        };
        return B;
    })();
    Widget.B = B;
})(Widget || (Widget = {}));

},{}]},{},[2,1]);
```

As you can see, when A tried to extend Widget.B it fails because .B hasn't been defined yet.

Comment: Why would you need any specific order? If there are dependencies, declare them.

Comment: @bergi because it is a class that is extending another class. It's more than just a require('./file.js') call as the parent is lower in the file than the child resulting in an error.

Comment: Yes, the one class depends on the other. What's wrong with using `require`?

Comment: @bergi Not a dependency but an extension. The code is here: http://fiddlesalad.com/typescript/typescript-test-page (only way I can share both the TS and resulting JS code). Where in class A would I put require to extend class B?

Comment: That page doesn't load for me, but yes, when one component needs the other to work then that's called a dependency.

Comment: @bergi I updated the original post with the code. Sorry that didn't occur to me earlier.

Comment: According to https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Modules%20in%20TypeScript#Splitting_Across_Files, it shouldn't be a `require()` call but more a `/// <reference path="Widget.B.ts" />`. I don't know TS, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A large part of the point of browserify is to make load order not matter. `a` and `b` should be modules and `a` should `require('b')`.

I don't know TypeScript, but I think you need something like:

class A:

```
import B = require('./path/to/B');
export class A extends B {
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log('monkey: ', this.getMonkey());
    }
}
```

Class B:

```
export class B {
    private monkey = 'Baboon';
    public getMonkey() {
        return this.monkey;
    }
}
```

See [Modules in TypeScript > Going External](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Modules%20in%20TypeScript).

If you really want to buck the browserify system for some reason while bundling these modules with browserify, then you might need to first concatenate them in the order you want and supply the concatenated file to browserify. That could probably all be done with streams.

Comment: I understand that but there are instances (this one in particular) in which order matters.  If browserify has no method to control order there is a fairly good chance it will get removed from the process as the use to Typescript and the class based structure is non-negoitable.

Comment: Turns out Browserify simply won't allow it so I have the concatenation being done in grunt.  Thanks for the effort @JMM.

Comment: @AnthonyDeaver Did you try the suggestion to make your files independent modules that can be used with browserify?